# User-entered number of pages to print in MS Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, printing

Is it possible to have a user enter the desired number of pages they wish to print onto a form, and be able to print "Page X of Y" on each page?

I have a small shipping label application that requires a dynamic number of labels to be printed for any given shipment, and is entered by the user.

The data used for the label information is returned from the following stored procedure

```sql
SELECT C1.CompanyName,
        C1.Address1,
        C1.Address2,
        C1.City,
        C1.Province,
        C1.PostalCode,
        C2.CustomerName,
        C2.ShippingAddress1,
        C2.ShippingAddress2,
        C2.ShippingAddress3,
        C2.ShippingAddress4,
        C2.City,
        C2.Province,
        C2.PostalCode
FROM MyCompany_tb C1,
    Customer_tb C2
WHERE C2.CustomerID = @CUSTOMER_ID
    AND C2.InvoiceNumber = @INVOICE_NUMBER
```

This will produce a single record that includes my company "return address" information (C1), and pairs it with the the customer's shipping information (C2).  The label(s) that get
printed need to print out "Box 1 of 3", "Box 2 of 3", etc, depending on the value entered by the user.

I found [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-print-one-or-more-labels-for-a-single-access-record/), but I would prefer to do this without creating a "temp table" in Access.  Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional table, but it can be a simple [number](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/creative-solutions-by-using-a-number-table/) [table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11506/why-are-numbers-tables-invaluable), with one LongInt column `ID` with numbers 1..n

Then use a cartesian product to get the number of records you want.

In VBA:

```vb
' lngNumRecords is the number entered by the user
TempVars.Add "NumRecords", lngNumRecords
```

The query:

```sql
SELECT YourQuery.*, "Box " & [tblNumbers].[ID] & " of " & [TempVars]![NumRecords] AS BoxNo
FROM YourQuery, tblNumbers
WHERE tblNumbers.ID <= [TempVars]![NumRecords]
```

There is no JOIN, so you get your main record replicated as many times as IDs are specified.

This assumes that `YourQuery` returns exactly one record.